# What does <> mean?

Tags: inequality, logic, number-comparison

What do the less-than and greater-than symbols right next to each other mean?

Does it mean either less than *or* greater than? In other words, not equal?

I am trying to understand a book that says this:

> *A = B* and *B <> A* are logically contradictory

Comment: From the quote, that appears to be what the book is trying to convey. This is crass notation though. The book should be using $\neq$ instead.

Comment: If the book does not give a definition for this notation somewhere, then it is a really bad book.

Comment: That symbol is used in SQL. Are you reading a book on relational databases?

Comment: John: no, it is a sociology book from the 1930s

Comment: I've seen this occasionally used for $\neq$ in older books (more than 60-70 years).

Comment: Many programming languages use <> for 'not equal', including BASIC: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_operator#Standard_relational_operators . When working with posets, it's sometimes useful to talk about "greater-or-less-than" which is different from $\neq$ and can be typeset as $a \gtrless b$.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments, I have decided this probably means ≠ (not equal), as Theo said. As John said, it is also used in SQL, and I found it means not equal in that context, too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532435/what-does-mean

I found the original Italian version of the book, which says this:

“A è eguale a B, B non è eguale ad A, è inferiore ad A, sono logicamente contraddittorie”

According to my translation app, it means this:

“A is equal to B, B is not equal to A, is less than A, they are logically contradictory”

My guess is the translator(s) wanted to skip the part about B being less than A, and either they used a nonstandard symbol or the typesetter could not find a “≠”.